# phpunit & php-webdriver sharing a webdriver instance

Tags: php, curl, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phpunit

I'm trying to figure out how to share a single php-webdriver instance across multiple phpunit tests. The instance works fine for the first test but by the second test the driver's executor's curl resource has been lost.

setup-webdriver.php:

```
<?php

namespace Facebook\WebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
require_once('php-webdriver-community/vendor/autoload.php');

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
```

tests/GoogleTest.php:

```
<?php

class GoogleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testGoogleTitle() {

        global $driver;
        print_r($driver);
        $driver->get('http://www.google.com/');
        echo $driver->getTitle();
    }
}
```

tests/YahooTest.php:

```
<?php

class YahooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testYahooTitle()
    {
        global $driver;
        print_r($driver);
        $driver->get('http://www.yahoo.com/');
        echo $driver->getTitle();
    }
}
```

I'm running it via `/opt/local/bin/php56 /usr/local/bin/phpunit-5.1 --bootstrap setup-webdriver.php tests`

The Google test runs first, and works fine, but by the time the Yahoo test runs, it exits with

```
1) YahooTest::testYahooTitle
curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given
```

The full output is:

```
PHPUnit 5.1.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver Object
(
    [executor:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor Object
        (
            [url:protected] => http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
            [curl:protected] => Resource id #1007
        )

    [sessionID:protected] => 7b2577fa-98f1-4f75-9b18-a22a0b7474eb
    [mouse:protected] =>
    [keyboard:protected] =>
    [touch:protected] =>
    [executeMethod:protected] =>
)
GoogleE                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver Object
(
    [executor:protected] => Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor Object
        (
            [url:protected] => http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
            [curl:protected] => 0
        )

    [sessionID:protected] => 7b2577fa-98f1-4f75-9b18-a22a0b7474eb
    [mouse:protected] =>
    [keyboard:protected] =>
    [touch:protected] =>
    [executeMethod:protected] =>
)


Time: 2.67 seconds, Memory: 11.00Mb

There was 1 error:

1) YahooTest::testYahooTitle
curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given


/Users/robgudgeon/Downloads/code/phpunit-a-test/php-webdriver-community/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:227
/Users/robgudgeon/Downloads/code/phpunit-a-test/php-webdriver-community/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:507
/Users/robgudgeon/Downloads/code/phpunit-a-test/php-webdriver-community/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:187
/Users/robgudgeon/Downloads/code/phpunit-a-test/tests/YahooTest.php:9

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I only added the calls to `print_r($driver)` to try to figure out the reason for the error & it's obviously because the curl resource has changed from being a valid resource for the Google test, to being 0 by the time of the Yahoo test.

The reason for setting this up is that I have a full working test suite (for a work project) but currently it runs around 50 tests in a single script, and I'm trying to figure out how to split the tests into logical groups/files, whilst sharing the same webdriver instance - it seemed to me that the best way was to use the bootstrap file to set up the webdriver & then re-use it. The code I've shown is just a proof-of-concept, I'm well aware that calling print_r(), echo etc. within phpunit tests isn't the correct way to test things, I'm just trying to learn & understand how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use globals, use the fixtures available in PHPUnit

```
class BaseTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    static $driver;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {

        $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
        self::$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {

        self::$driver->close();
    }

    public function getDriver()
    {
        return self::$driver;
    }
}

class GoogleTest extends BaseTestCase
{

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->getDriver()->get('http://www.google.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {

        echo $this->getDriver()->getTitle();
    }

    public function testSomethingElse()
    {
        // do test
    }
}


class YahooTest extends BaseTestCase
{

    public function testYahooTitle()
    {
        $this->getDriver()->get('http://www.yahoo.com/');
        echo $this->getDriver()->getTitle();
    }
}
```

This example won't share the same $driver between both GoogleTest and YahooTest but that is recommended as you will want a clean slate for each test.

However all the tests in GoogleTest **will** share the same driver.
The execution order of tests, when you do 'phpunit tests' will be:

```
setUpBeforeClass() 

setUp()
testTitle()

setUp()
testSomethingElse()

tearDownAfterClass()
```

I recommend reading a bit more about [fixtures](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got it working more like how I expected now. I should have explained a little more about what I'm trying to achieve - there are various sections of our intranet site that sit behind authentication, so some of the test groups will need to authenticate before running the tests, but obviously I only want them to authenticate once per set of tests. I've achieved this by adding a static login() method to the BaseTestClass & then having a testLogin() method that calls $this::login(); for each set of tests that needs to authenticate. Thanks for the heads up on fixtures too :)